# Why are exponential smoothing forecasts look same for the following days? R ets forecast package

Tags: r, forecasting, exponential

I would like to use exponential smoothing to forecast solar irradiance for 5 days, but forecasts look all same. I have read the documentation of ets package and tried different Additive, Multiplicative model, but could not fix the problem. My data consists 30 days of hourly measurements and I would like to forecast day from 31 to 35.

Here is my code

```
library(forecast)

mydatatsfreq <- ts(mydata, frequency = 24)
fit <- ets(mydatatsfreq, model='ZZZ')
summary(fit)
```

> ETS(A,Ad,A)
>
> Call:  ets(y = mydatatsfreq, model = "ZZZ")
>
> Smoothing parameters:
>       alpha = 0.9971 
>       beta  = 1e-04 
>       gamma = 2e-04 
>       phi   = 0.9788
>
> Initial states:
>       l = 6.5994 
>       b = -0.0745 
>       s=-8.5981 -8.3857 -8.2845 -8.4552 -8.5558 -8.6233
>              -8.662 -6.5815 5.5694 15.1411 20.8226 22.4551 23.014 20.7874 15.5312 7.1746 -3.5179 -8.8709 -8.8073 -8.5763 -8.6457 -8.74 -8.6555 -8.5355
>
> sigma:  1.7493
>
> ```
>  AIC     AICc      BIC
> ```
>
> 5593.623 5596.326 5730.958
>
> Training set error measures:
>                        ME     RMSE       MAE MPE MAPE      MASE       ACF1 Training set 0.00722588 1.749286 0.8136336 NaN  Inf 0.6419291
>   0.05326251

This is the plot of forecasts

[image]

Comment: your question could use some more explanation e.g. why do you think the forecasts are not correct? have you tried something like `forecast(fit, h= 5)` for example?

Comment: thanks for the reply. the plot is the result of plot(forecast(fit, h=24*5)). I think the forecasts are wrong because it is solar irradiance forecasts, so it should change for all days.